# Has there ever been a consultation chess match?

Tags: history, tournament, match

Inspired by [How much stronger is a team of GMs compared to a single GM?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/21828/how-much-stronger-is-a-team-of-gms-compared-to-a-single-gm)

All the chess matches I'm aware of have been 1v1. There have been team competitions such as the Olympiads, but I am not sure if you are allowed to discuss moves with your teammates in Olympiads. I assume not since news reports don't usually mention the teammates discussing. If so then Olympiads are just a series of 1v1 games.

I am wondering if there has ever been a consultation chess tournament/match of the kind where a group of players play against another group of players, and both sides are able to talk and discuss moves before they are made. If so, I'd like details of the tournament/match.

A few close cases:

1. [Hand and brain chess](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/34972/in-hand-and-brain-chess-is-the-stronger-player-generally-preferred-to-be-the-ha), although the hand and brain are not supposed to talk.
2. [Kasparov vs. the world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kasparov_versus_the_World) was sort of a consultation game, but it was also a correspondence game since the time control was very long. I am looking only for OTB games.
3. another close case: pair matches eg [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dBGuCcJkuz4) or the [mixed sex version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4iF86T8RUrk), although the teams are not supposed to talk.

Comment: How notable does it need to be? I'm sure there have been plenty of casual 2v2 games over the years. Do they count?

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon being reported by major chess websites (e.g. Chess.com, Chessbase, Chessdom ...) would suffice. Or if it's recorded by major chess databases, e.g. Lichess, Chessgames, Caissabase.

Comment: Do 1v2 games count, or do there need to be multiple people on each side?

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon I prefer multiple vs. multiple, although if you are aware of any 1v2 games I would still find them interesting.

Comment: You might be interested in chess.com vs chessbruhs team match, that feature Danny and Robert vs Eric and Aman.

Comment: @Akavall you should post that as an answer =)

Comment: If you're looking for OTB, it seems to me that you should put that in the beginning. And a consultation game pretty much necessitates not being a traditional OTB game, as you can't fit a lot of people around a board, and if the consultations are in private, then that requires a private space, although the moves themselves can be made OTB.

Comment: @Acccumulation presumably you could still have one group speak, e.g., Italian while the other group speaks French, and neither would understand the other.

Comment: @Allure Italian team: "Dovremmo fiancetto?" French team: "Qu'es ce que cela pourrai possiblement dire?"

Comment: another close case: pair matches? eg [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dBGuCcJkuz4) or the [mixed sex version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4iF86T8RUrk)

Comment: what about [vote chess eg on chess.com](https://www.chess.com/clubs/forum/view/what-is-vote-chess2) ?

Comment: @Acccumulation Well........ils ont dit 'fianchetto' soooooo...?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A chessgames.com user has made a [compilation](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chesscollection?cid=1009156) of consultation games. For example, it contains [Lasker / Pillsbury vs Steinitz / Chigorin](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1109122). According to a comment by user TheFocus, it was "played in St. Petersburg, Russia on January 29, 1896."

Comment: "Soyuz 9 Cosmonauts vs Ground Control" entertaining

Answer (score 2):

2024 Update:

There's an inaugural chess.com tournament in 2024 called 'Team Chess' won by [C-squared podcast: Fabiano Caruana & Cristian Chirila](https://www.chess.com/events/2024-team-chess-battle/results).